# How can I expand/shrink selection in WebStorm on Mac?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, webstorm, keymapping

It seems that in ReSharper or IntelliJ Idea you can expand selection from expression to method to surrounding block etc. This should be possible to do via `ctrl-W`, but that does not seem to work in WebStorm on my Mac. Is there a way to do it or is such functionality disabled in WebStorm for some reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/documentation/WebStorm_ReferenceCard_80.pdf, try using "Option/Alt + Arrow key Up" for "Select successively increasing code blocks" action